# memory issue with linux 32-bit application

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

C++ application taking too long with mmap2 system call. Once the process reaches to roughly ~2.7 GB, the mmap2 call takes upto 100 seconds and its being killed by heart beat mechanism built in the process.  Started an strace for the process, when the process memory reaches close to ~ 2GB RSS the strace was showing mmap2 was returning ENOMEM but the application was 
allocated memory.

OS: redhat 6.5 64-bit compiler: gcc 4.4.6 process memory limit(32 bit): 4 gb,
No Swap configured

And when this happens the host still has 50GB of memory left.

We tried to increase  vm.max_map_count from 65530 to 1000000, it improved a little the mmap2 ENOMEM was delayed but the process eventually gets killed as 
mmap2 system call taked too long.

We also proved with a test program that we can allocate and use upto ~4GB.

From the strace it looks like not an application issue  as mmap2 is requesting memory from the kernel and would like to know why mmap2 is taking too long.

stack trace when mmap2 is taking > 100 seconds and eventually getting killed by heart beat mechanism:

```
    #0  0x55575430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
    #1  0x560f9dd8 in mmap () from /lib/libc.so.6
    #2  0x5608cc14 in new_heap () from /lib/libc.so.6
    #3  0x5608f17f in _int_malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
    #4  0x5608fb7e in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
    #5  0x55fb509a in operator new(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    #6  0x0830b051 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<unsigned long> >::allocate (this=0xb642b04, __n=1) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:89

Following is snapshot from strace:

    ---successful mmap2 
2211  21:31:18 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffffffffe0e01000 <0.000454>
2211  21:31:20 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffffffffe0700000 <0.000379>
2211  21:31:20 mmap2(NULL, 524288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x57b12000 <0.000042>
2211  21:31:25 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffffffffe0700000 <0.000359>
2211  21:31:25 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffffffffe0e01000 <0.000021>
2211  21:31:25 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xffffffffe1502000 <0.000020>

    ----encountered first ENOMEM a day later
2211  12:21:28 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory) <0.000444>
2211  12:21:28 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory) <0.000140>
2211  12:21:29 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffffde01000 <0.000482>
2211  12:21:30 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffffd700000 <0.000649>
2211  12:21:31 mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffffc500000 <0.000582>
2211  12:21:31 mmap2(NULL, 7344128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffffe502000 <0.000634>

    ---------mmap2 taking more than 100 seconds
2211  13:04:25 mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory) <0.000179>
2211  13:04:25 mmap2(NULL, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory) <0.000158>
2211  13:04:25 mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory) <0.000191>
2211  13:04:25 mmap2(NULL, 1048576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory) <0.000252>
2211  13:04:25 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 <unfinished ...>
```

Comment: This is really just a hunch: To me, this looks like an address space fragmentation issue. You are allocating mappings of significantly different sizes, and you seem to be letting them build up over time. The larger allocations fail first. What I really can't explain is the 100 second delay that you encounter. That sounds like a kernel bug. Have you tried recompiling as 64 bit? That might at least fix the issue for you.

Comment: @cmaster, we are dependent on some third party libraries which are 32-bit.